# Custom Font in ExpandableListView Android

Tags: android, listview, fonts, expandablelistview

I wanted to make custom font for one of my textview but i'm still getting

```
cannot resolve method getAssets()
```

Here is a part of code:

```
    @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    Utils.setFontAllView((ViewGroup)convertView);

    TextView txtListChild   = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtcardname);
    txtListChild.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    TextView kategoria  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.kategoria);
    kategoria.setText(this.KATEGORIE[numerKategori]);


    custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/capture.ttf");
    txtListChild.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

I want to make it with this code:

```
custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/capture.ttf");
        txtListChild.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code to this it will work:

```
custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/capture.ttf");
```

You can't access your assets without context of your view. So Context is mandatory

instead of setting the fonts inside getView method you can define fonts in your custom textview class, by using this it will take less memory and your app performance will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can call getAssets with a context. Use this:

```
custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this._context.getAssets(), "fonts/capture.ttf");
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**As you want to use it into Adapter from your code**

**Do the below changes**

**Use Context**

**Make Sure in your asset folder under fonts there is file of capture.ttf**

**check Path for file capture.ttf**

```
 Context context = null;
            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/capture.ttf");
      txtListChild.setTypeface(custom_font);
```